# App Engine JPA Entity relationships

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I'm new to App Engine and trying to figure out how to use relationships between entities.
I'm using JPA and having trouble to understand how to organize the relationships.

I have three classes City, Hotel and Attraction. I want cities to be standalone and able to be created on it's own. Every city has a list of all available hotels in the city. The hotel always need a city and can only have one city. Attractions have to have a city, but a city doesn't need to know about the attractions.

Classes:

```
 @Entity(name = "City")
 public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(??)
    private List<Hotel> hotels;


    //getters and setters
}

@Entity(name = "Hotel")
public class Hotel {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;

  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(??)
  private City city;
}


@Entity(name = "Attraction")
public class Attraction {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @Unowned??
  private City city;

  //getters and setters
}
```

I've been looking all over the web, but i can't find any good tutorials on this. Would really appreciate any pointers in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [series of posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine-java/JDO%242FJPA%2420Snippets%2420That%2420Work) - "JDO/JPA Snippets That Work" on appengine java google group, which is a good starting point.

[This one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/VMg9xiQv1jM) shows how to create a bidirectional, owned, one-to-many relationship.